# Natbib references does not appear in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I want to have a bibliography like this one

[image]

I tried different natbib styles but until now I was not successful.

My code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Support for more character glyphs
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}\citeindextrue % Round brackets around citations, change to square for square brackets
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required to include images
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,theorem} % Math packages
\usepackage{booktabs} % Required for better horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{xspace} % Provides the ability to use an intelligent space which is used in \institution and \department
\usepackage{acronym} % Include a list of acronyms
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating} % Allows tables and figures to be rotated
\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for links and changing link options
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage{textcomp} %Sopecial symbols
\usepackage{gensymb} % Special symbols like °C
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% Allows include PDF files
\usepackage{adjustbox} % Required to fit table to the page
\usepackage{float} %unflota and place figures and tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
Some random text \citep{IRENA2015}, more text and something something cites \citep{web:TWB2016, AlIbrahim2006}.


\bibliographystyle{apalike} % Use the plainnat bibliography style
\bibliography{biblio} % Use the bibliography.bib file as the source of references
\end{document}
```

My biblio file is like this:

```
@Misc{IRENA2015,
  author={IRENA},
  title={RENEWABLE ENERGY IN THE WATER, ENERGY {\&} FOOD NEXUS},
  howpublished={Available online at \url{http://www.irena.org/DocumentDownloads/Publications/IRENA_Water_Energy_Food_Nexus_2015.pdf}},
  year={2015},
  note={Consulted on: 07/04/2016}
}

@Misc{web:TWB2016,
  publisher={World Bank},
  title={World Bank databank},
  year={2016},
  note={Consulted on: 16/01/2016},
  url={http://databank.worldbank.org/data/reports.aspx?source=global-economic-monitor-%28gem%29-commodities#},
  author={WB}
}

@article{AlIbrahim2006,
    year  = {2006},
    month = {jun},
    publisher = {International Society for Horticultural Science ({ISHS})},
    number = {710},
    pages = {251--264},
    author = {A. AlIbrahim and N. AlAbbadi and I. AlHelal},
    title = {{PV} {GREENHOUSE} {SYSTEM} {SYSTEM} {DESCRIPTION},  {PERFORMANCE} {AND} {LESSON} {LEARNED}},
    journal = {Acta Hortic.}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you run the normal cycle of compilations: pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex (twice)?

Answer (score 1):

After all citations commands have been entered and are stable -- omit loading of `natbib` package and use `\cite` instead of `\citep`.

I can't help but comment on two aspects of the stub bibliography. First, do encase `World Bank` (in the `title` field) in a pair of curly braces; that way, BibTeX won't lowercase the "B" in "Bank". Second, if you really prefer to use the `apalike` bibliography style (rather than the `plainnat` style, which is mentioned in a comment), don't use a field named `url`. `apalike` is a really old style, from the latex 1980s, i.e., an era before the Internet was around and URLs were quite unknown. If you do want to print out the information in the `url` field, move the information to the `note` field and encase the URL string in a `\url` directive.

Comment: Yes, I use plainnat, but trying to get the tags for my bibliography I tried different styles. That's why apalike appears in my example. But I appreciate your comments.